# skeletons and coskeletons of a simplicial set

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Absolute beginner in simplicial homotopy theory (and category theory) here. Trying to understand the idea of skeletons and coskeletons of a simplicial set.

Let $\mathbf\Delta$ be the simplex category, $\mathbf S$ be the category of simplicial sets, and $X: \mathbf\Delta^{op} \to Set$ be a simplicial set. The n-skeleton of $X$ is defined to be the simplicial subset $sk_nX=\bigcup_{\tau \in Mor_{\mathbf S}(\Delta^n,X)}\tau(\Delta^n)$, where $\Delta^n$ is the standard n-simplex $Mor_{\mathbf\Delta}(-,[n])$.

I.e. we have $sk_nX([m])=\bigcup\tau(Mor([m],[n]))\subseteq X_m$ in particular we have $sk_nX([n])=X_n$ by Yoneda Lemma.

If $Y$ is another simplicial set, apparently there is the following bijection:

(1) $Mor(sk_nX,Y) \cong Mor(X_{\leq n},Y_{\leq n})$ where $X_{\leq n}$ is the restriction of $X$ to the full subcategory $\mathbf\Delta_{\leq n}^{op}$.

How is this constructed? If we have a natural transformation $\eta \in Mor_{\mathbf S}(sk_nX,Y)$, then $\eta_{n}$ certainly is a morphism (of sets) from $sk_nX([n])=X_n \to Y_n$. What about for $m \lt n$ and $m \gt n$? We have $\eta_m: sk_nX([m]) \subseteq X_m \to Y_m$. How do we extend the morphism to all of $X_m$? Conversely, if we have a natural transformation $X_{\leq n}\to Y_{\leq n}$, then for each $m \leq n$ we can restrict to a morphism $sk_nX([m]) \to Y_m$. What about for $m \gt n$?

The n-coskeleton of $X$ is defined to be the simplicial set $csk_n X$ such that $csk_nX([m])=Mor(sk_n \Delta^m,X)$. Again, there is a bijection:

(2) $Mor(X_{\leq n},Y_{\leq n}) \cong Mor(X,csk_nY)$. How is this constructed?

Comment: There is an obvious map $sk_nY\rightarrow Y$ given by inclusion. Hence you get a map $sk_nX\rightarrow sk_nY\rightarrow Y$. In the other direction, note that the simplcial identies force a map $sk_nX\rightarrow Y$ to take values in $sk_nY$.

Comment: @Tyrone so are you saying that the set of natural morphisms $sk_nX \to sk_nY$ are in bijection with the set of natural morphisms $X_{\leq n} \to Y_{\leq 
 n}$? how do I see this?? I think the main problem I have is I don't see how the subset of simplices $sk_nX([m])$ as defined above is sitting inside of $X_m$.

Comment: What text are you following?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this can still help you now, but I think the bijection (2) follows directly from the adjoint property of the functor 'res'(which is sometimes called the n-th sk) and the functor 'cosk'.